# error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Object'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Very simple project, no tsconfig.json just using the command line:

```
tsc --jsx react --target es6 --lib dom src/lib/Fetch.tsx
```

and I get the following errors and I don't understand why, these types are literally defined everywhere, and specifically in lib.es6.d.ts which is I believe included by `--target es6`

```
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Boolean'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Function'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'IArguments'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Number'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Object'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'RegExp'.
```

Have the following dependencies installed

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
  "@types/react": "^16.3.16",
  "react": "^16.4.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^10.3.1",
  "typescript": "^2.9.1"
}
```

*RESOLVED*

Figured out my problem.  Having typescript installed locally, but was running the globally installed and older version typescript.  When I ran tsc via npm scripts it compiles with the following command:

```
tsc --jsx react --target es6 --module commonjs src/lib/Fetch.tsx
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`dom` contains just the definitions for browser specific DOM elements. You need to include one of the `es*` libraries which includes the core es types needed for compilation. Once you specify a `--lib` option you have to include all necessary types, the compiler will no longer include any library based on your target:

```
tsc --jsx react --target es6 --lib es2015,dom src/lib/Fetch.tsx
```

Or if you are not actually just using the default libraries, you can just omit the option altogether:

```
tsc --jsx react --target es6 src/lib/Fetch.tsx
```

Comment: Neither of those work unfortunately.  They both complains about AbortController, csstype (in @types/react/index.d.ts) and something about RequestInt and signal.

I built a more isolated example, going to update my question with the details.

Comment: @AustinFrance try with a higher es library version es2018 for example. But the specific error of those built - in types not being found is caused by the lack of a default es library.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I was running the globally installed older version of typescript when I have a newer version installed locally.  If I run tsc through npm, my original code it works fine, though I had to also include --module commonjs to prevent @types/react complaining.

Comment: Going to mark yours as the answer, because given just the context of the question, adding --lib dom does produce the errors seen, and removing --lib dom corrects that, as you suggested.

Comment: Check your tsconfig.json. You can also, and usually do, specify this there.